# How to fix "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project" on a Project will Billing enabled?

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, geocoding, google-cloud-billing

I'm trying to replace the API key for a website I made that takes a given address and renders it in Google maps. When I try and use it I get this[image: google maps error]

and this

```
You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started
```

When I click the link to add billing, nothing changes. When I check on my billing account to see if it's attached to the project housing the key, it is connected. When I check the project itself to see if it has billing, it says it does.

The other person who asked a very similar question had people saying to create a brand new project and a brand new billing account. I tried this and I'm still having the problem. I also tried to create a new billing account as a "Google Maps Platform" as another user suggested

***(His screenshot)*** [image: create new billing maps platform] but that option does not exist for me.

***(My Screenshot on the same page)*** [image: create new billing]

I'm at a complete loss here. Are there any other solutions people have found for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This error **often** means there is a problem with the Google Payments account associated with the billing account. Double-check that your payment information is correct. Some credit/debit cards do not work with Google payments.

You can test that your card works by making a small prepayment on your account. However, success does not mean that the credit/debit card can be used for recurring payments (that is an issue with some countries) but the prepayment will allow you to use the account (in most cases).

[Google Payments Account](https://payments.google.com/)

Another item to double-check is the type of billing account. There are two: Google Cloud Platform and Google Maps Platform. In the Google Billing Accounts page, look for **Enabled Google service**., It should show **Google Maps Platform**.

[Google Maps Platform Billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing)

From your screenshot, I see that you are in India. Most credit/debit cards from India refuse Google payments. If this is the case, you will need to use a different credit/debit card or you will need to prepay your account. Other options are to switch to **invoiced billing** or set up an account with a Google partner.

[(Customers in India) Automatic payments declined due to Reserve Bank of India (RBI) regulations](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#resolve-india-autopay)

The following links provide options:

[Make a manual payment or pay early](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manual-payment)

[Apply for monthly invoiced billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/invoiced-billing)

[Find the right Google Cloud partner](https://cloud.withgoogle.com/partners/)

Comment: Hi sorry if it wasn't clear, the 2nd image wasn't mine, it was an example I found elsewhere to show what I was 'not' seeing, I'm in the USA using a United States Credit Card.

Is there an issue with Paypal? Because that's what I have set as my primary payment. And it works for my google drive subscription and YouTube premium subscription. I would really prefer not to spend money just to see if a card works on Google Cloud Specifically, it wont let me spend less than $10. I haven't even used the API enough to be charged for anything yet. Surely there's another way to know if a card is valid?

Comment: @ChristopherBurwell - You can check your Google Payments account. It will indicate if there is a problem usually. You will also see a $1.00 charge that is refunded. If you have not seen that charge, then your payment method was declined. I do not use Paypal so I cannot offer advice for their service. In any event, I have provided you with links to documentation to help you solve your problem. Another option is to open a Google Cloud Billing support ticket https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Comment: One last note. The fail-safe method is to use a real credit card. Then you can call your bank (card issuer) for help using the card. Some debit cards also offer assistance. They can look up the error code on refused payments or refused authorizations (such as the $1.00 charge that is refunded).

Comment: I bit the bullet and prepaid, the money went through and the key still isn't working. I think my best bet will be billing support.

Comment: Wait a few hours as the billing system is not instant on. You can open a billing ticket while waiting but wait at least one hour unless an emergency. In my experience, billing support is very good and very fast in solving problems.